# Converting 2 chars to its ascii binary code

Tags: c++, casting, binary

I'm reading binary data in character format from an accelerometer and it consists of higher byte and lower byte. It's a long time since I worked with C++ and usually only used higher level stuff.
I have the following function:

```
short char2short(char* hchar, char* lchar)
{
    char temp[2];
    temp[0] = *hchar;
    temp[1] = *lchar;
```

How can I get that values converted to an integer?
atoi works different as far as I know (e.g. "21" = 21).
Can I just typecast char to int? But how does it work with higher bit and lower bit?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the bytes as unsigned to avoid issues with shifting sign bits.

```
short char2short(unsigned char hchar, unsigned char lchar)
{
    return static_cast<short>(lchar | (hchar << 8));
}
```

You may also want to use unsigned short. It depends what you expect.

Comment: You stopped half-way: `uint8_t` would be the right type for 8-bit arguments. `char` (wether signed or unsigned) might actually not. Same for the result: use `uint16_t`. Note that you need to cast the result of the operation, as that is `int`, not `short` or `uint16_t`. Otherwise you might get a truncation warning (depending on `sizeof(int)` ).

Comment: I just used the types in his question.. but you are right about the cast.

Comment: The cast is redundant; the `return` expression gets converted to the return type anyway

Comment: @MattMcNabb The cast is redundant, but some compilers warn about implicit casts to smaller data types.